# Тире или запятая с тире

Tags: пунктуация

Здравствуйте! Подскажите, пожалуйста, на месте () лучше поставить "—" или ",—"
Или, может, достаточно и просто запятой? "Я люблю домашний хлеб() испеченный в русской печи, он кажется особенно ароматным, хрустящим и мягким".

Answer (score 2):

***Я люблю домашний хлеб: испеченный в русской печи, он кажется особенно ароматным, хрустящим и мягким.*** Ставим двоеточие перед второй частью бессоюзного предложения, так как вторая часть указывает на причину того, о чём говорится в первой части.

Запятая после причастного оборота *испечённый в русской печи* тоже необходима, потому что оборот имеет обстоятельственное значение причины.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь. Честно говоря, до сих пор до конца не пойму разницу между двоеточием и тире. Вернее, привыкла что двоеточие обычно ставится при дальнейшем перечислении чего-либо.

Comment: Найдите в учебниках материал "Знаки препинания в бессоюзном сложном предложении" и просто выучите, когда ставится тире, когда двоеточие. Бывают сложные случаи, когда вместо двоеточия стаится тире, но в вашем примере всё прозрачно и просто. Это вы усвоите легко.

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо!

Comment: Екатерина, тире в этом примере тоже вполне корректно.

Comment: Простите, никак не могу согласиться.

Comment: Екатерина, из справочника Лопатина. В бессоюзном сложном предложении при обозначении пояснения, причины, обоснования, изъяснения допустимо употребление тире вместо двоеточия (особенно в художественной литературе и в публицистике). Вот, в частности, примеры из произведений К. Паустовского: Изредка в небе светилось голубоватое пятно — за тучками пробивалась луна, но тотчас гасла; Подснежники, наверное, уже прорастали в земле — их слабый травянистый запах просачивался сквозь снег; С

Comment: Розенталь. Вариативны двоеточие и тире в бессоюзных сложных предложениях с причинно-следственными отношениями. Ср.:

Последние дни флажки на карте не двигались: положение оставалось без перемен (Сим.); А углубляться мы не могли — земля промёрзла (Гран.).

Comment: http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=189#pp189

Answer (score 1):

Если честно... 
 "Я люблю домашний хлеб. Испеченный в русской печи, он кажется особенно ароматным, хрустящим и мягким".
Так проще и понятнее.

Answer (score 1):

1) Двоеточием обозначаем следственно-причинную связь в БСП: Я люблю домашний хлеб: испеченный в русской печи, он кажется особенно ароматным, хрустящим и мягким

2) Тире обозначаем взаимообусловленность предложений в БСП, но без указания конкретной направленности "следствие-причина": Я люблю домашний хлеб - испеченный в русской печи, он кажется особенно ароматным, хрустящим и мягким.

В первом случае предупредительная интонация, увеличенная пауза. Во втором случае присоединительная интонация: пауза короче, но полное понижение голоса в конце первого предложения.

Answer (score -2):

Верно будет использовать двоеточие.

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?